# How can i make a GPIO F5 Button

Tags: gpio, python, keyboard

I have a GPIO button triggering an `os.system("sudo reboot")` command.

How can I change the reboot command to send <kbd>F5</kbd> to the active window (web kiosk).

Answer (score -2):

install xautomation

```
    os.system("xte 'key F5'")
```

Comment: A litle more detail on how exactly to do this would be helpful. Like where do you enter the code above, how do you make sure this runs at startup etc.